# I can't access my request.body object in Koa JS (I am using body parser middleware but still it's not working)

Tags: javascript, koa, koa-bodyparser

My main server.js File

```
const koa = require("koa");
const Router = require("koa-router");
const bodyParser = require("koa-bodyparser");

const app = new koa();
var router = new Router();

// app.use(bodyParser({ enableTypes: ["json", "text"] }));
// I have also tried passing enabletypes parameteres but it still is not working..
 
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());

router.post("/", async (ctx) => {
  console.log(ctx);

});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port no ${PORT}`));
```

When i hit this router.post("/") end point ... just for the purpose to see my context object i console logged the context object and it shows the following in the console when I hit this endpoint using postman (i am send JSON body in the request)

[image]

My postman request

[image]

**How do I access my body (JSON object) ?**

Comment: You might want to look into why you're getting a 404.

Comment: no, i just can't access my body.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

To access your body object, try the following:

```
const body = ctx.request.body;
```

Secondly: because in one of the comments there was a note, why you get a 404. I guess this is because in your route you are not returning anything. So your route could look like:

```
router.post("/", async (ctx) => {
  const body = ctx.request.body;
  console.log(body);

  return (true)                   // or whatever you want to return to the client
});
```

Comment: He is already logging the whole ctx. What you are suggesting doesn't make a difference since ctx.request.body is not defined according to his console logs.

Comment: He is already logging the whole ctx and that shows a `'content-length': 380` so there is definetely some data therein. Sebastian is right `ctx,request.body` is what is needed as stated in the documentation right here: https://github.com/koajs/bodyparser#koa-bodyparser. Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using something to return i.e. if you return nothing you are going to get a 404 with Koa.  Just set the body of the ctx i.e. `ctx.body="something here"`.

Other than that depending on what you are using in the app to hit it Postman may work slightly different and pass additional headers etc.  I've run into this a handful of times using Thunder Client on VS Code where it works when poking it but in the app something is slightly off.  I've ONLY run into this with Koa and never express so might be worth checking and logging along the way WITHIN the app.